# How to execute 2 javascript function simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 javascript function that will be used as an object property. I want to run two functions simultaneously. I have joined them to `planogram` function but still not worked and give error. Here's my code.

```
    function planogram(node, pt, gridpt) {
        avoidNodeOverlap(node, pt, gridpt);
        stayInGroup(node, pt, gridpt);
    }

      // a Part.dragComputation function that prevents a Part from being dragged to overlap another Part
    function avoidNodeOverlap(node, pt, gridpt) {

        // this assumes each node is fully rectangular
        var bnds = node.actualBounds;
        var locate = node.location;

        // see if the area at the proposed location is unoccupied
        // use PT instead of GRIDPT if you want to ignore any grid snapping behavior
        var x = gridpt.x - (locate.x - bnds.x);
        var y = gridpt.y - (locate.y - bnds.y);
        var r = new go.Rect(x, y, bnds.width, bnds.height);

        // maybe inflate R if you want some space between the node and any other nodes
        if (isUnoccupied(r, node)) return pt;  // OK
        return locate;  // give up -- don't allow the node to be moved to the new location      
    }

    function stayInGroup(part, pt, gridpt) {
        // don't constrain top-level nodes
        var grp = part.containingGroup;
        if (grp === null) return pt;
        // try to stay within the background Shape of the Group
        var back = grp.findObject("rack");
        if (back === null) return pt;
        // allow dragging a Node out of a Group if the Shift key is down
        if (part.diagram.lastInput.shift) return pt;
        var p1 = back.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.TopLeft);
        var p2 = back.getDocumentPoint(go.Spot.BottomRight);
        var b = part.actualBounds;
        var loc = part.location;
        // find the padding inside the group's placeholder that is around the member parts
        var m = (grp.placeholder !== null ? grp.placeholder.padding : new go.Margin(0));
        // now limit the location appropriately
        var x = Math.max(p1.x + m.left, Math.min(pt.x, p2.x - m.right - b.width - 1)) + (loc.x-b.x);
        var y = Math.max(p1.y + m.top, Math.min(pt.y, p2.y - m.bottom - b.height - 1)) + (loc.y-b.y);
        return new go.Point(x, y);
    }
```

I also tried to call `stayInGroup` function inside `avoidNodeOverlap` function, but `stayInGroup` function be ignored. If any one have an idea to help I really appreciate it. sorry for my bad grammar, thanks

Comment: @Satpal why it would execute parallel ?

Comment: @Satpal still not worked

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to execute these 2 functions in sequential order OR you want to execute these in parallel?

JavaScript runs Asynchronously, so in the code example posted in your message, the functions are being called parallels/asynchronously.

If you want to execute them in linear sequential order you need to create the function callbacks and execute the 2nd function in the callback handler of 1st function.

Comment: would you give me a few sample? i can using both (parallel or linear). i just want my function worked

Comment: From your code 
`function planogram(node, pt, gridpt) {
        avoidNodeOverlap(node, pt, gridpt);
        stayInGroup(node, pt, gridpt);
 }`
 the 2 functions are being called asyncrhonously. By looking at the code the only reason for `stayInGroup` not producing the expected result is the `if` condition on line no. 3 of your method `stayInGroup`. Have you verified the value being passed to make sure that the method call is not making an early exit from line no. 3?

 Also, can you provide more details on the error being generated if there is any error?

Comment: the error is `Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`. Inside `stayInGroup` function I give an alert after `if (grp === null) return pt;` line but my alert doesn't executed. if i give an alert before `var grp = part.containingGroup;` it works. 

Note : that functions is actually worked. but if i joined them, i get trouble.

Comment: Im not sure of the object properties of `node` parameter being passed to `stayInGroup()`. But when the object is being unboxed on line no. 1 `var grp = part.containingGroup;` the call night be failing. You can check all the attributes of the `node` parameter. By default the objects being passed in javascript are passed by reference hence if `node` parameter which is passed to `avoidNodeOverlap()` is updated then its impact will appear in next function call as well. Worth checking it.

Comment: I have checked node and grp variable. although the grp value is null, it's still worked. recently I changed my planogram function like this.

`var pf = [];
function planogram(node, pt, gridpt){
  pf.push(avoidNodeOverlap(node, pt, gridpt), stayInGroup(node, pt, gridpt));
  while(pf.length != 0){
   return pf.pop();
  }
 }`

it works, but only get `stayInGroup` function. it's prove that node parameter passed to `stayInGroup` function. do you know how to use all function?